# Mailman and Apache Virtual Hosts problems

Tags: apache-2.2, postfix, apache-2.4, mailman

I am creating a set up of Mailman, Apache2.4 and Postfix.
My problem is as follows. When I access the mailing list with the domain name, I get the correct result in my browser. Here the picture

[image: Normal mailman front page]

However if I try to access directly using my server's IP address, I get a different page, where the mailing lists are missing. This is how it looks like:

[image]
The desired result is getting exactly the same page.

The apache2 configuration is as follows:

```
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/>
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    # (Old apache2.2 style configuration:)
    # Order allow,deny
    # Allow from all
    # New apache 2.4 configuration:
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/lib/mailman/archives/public/>
    Options FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride None
    # (Old configuration:)
    # Order allow,deny
    # Allow from all
    # New apache 2.4 configuration:
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/images/mailman/>
    AllowOverride None
    # (Old configuration:)
    # Order allow,deny
    # Allow from all 
    # New apache 2.4 configuration:
    Require all granted
</Directory>


<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName lists.example.org
DocumentRoot /var/www/lists
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/lists-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/lists-access.log combined

<Directory /var/lib/mailman/archives/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

Alias /archives/ /var/lib/mailman/archives/public/
Alias /images/mailman/ /usr/share/images/mailman/
ScriptAlias /admin /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/admin
ScriptAlias /admindb /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/admindb
ScriptAlias /confirm /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/confirm
ScriptAlias /create /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/create
ScriptAlias /edithtml /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/edithtml
ScriptAlias /listinfo /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo
ScriptAlias /options /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/options
ScriptAlias /private /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/private
ScriptAlias /rmlist /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/rmlist
ScriptAlias /roster /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/roster
ScriptAlias /subscribe /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/subscribe
ScriptAlias /mailman/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/
ScriptAlias / /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/
</VirtualHost>
```

EDIT: I include here my mm_cfg.py file (Mailman configuration):

```
from Defaults import *

MAILMAN_SITE_LIST = 'mailman'

DEFAULT_URL_PATTERN = 'http://%s/'
# PRIVATE_ARCHIVE_URL = '/cgi-bin/mailman/private'
PUBLIC_ARCHIVE_URL = 'http://%(hostname)s/archives/%(listname)s'
IMAGE_LOGOS         = '/mailman-icons/'

# Default domain for email addresses of newly created MLs
DEFAULT_EMAIL_HOST = 'lists.example.org'

# Default host for web interface of newly created MLs
DEFAULT_URL_HOST   = 'lists.example.org'

VIRTUAL_HOSTS.clear()
add_virtualhost(DEFAULT_URL_HOST,DEFAULT_EMAIL_HOST)

DEFAULT_SERVER_LANGUAGE = 'en'
USE_ENVELOPE_SENDER    = 0              # Still used?
DEFAULT_SEND_REMINDERS = 0
MTA='Postfix'
```

Besides that, I disable the default site by running:

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default
```

I noticed that if I don't disable 000-default, accessing the webpage using the IP address gives me the default Apache page that says everything is ok.

I wonder if there is some elegant solution to the direct IP access problem, making it show the same page as the one I see when I use the domain name.

EDIT: I tried changing to (Inside mm_cfg.py):

```
VIRTUAL_HOSTS.clear()
add_virtualhost("104.131.98.138","lists.example.org")
```

As suggested. I get the correct page when I use the url lists.example.org, however when I use the IP address I get this:
[image: Entering mailman directly using IP]

Note however that this time the email address is correct.

I get the same results also when both lines are present:

```
VIRTUAL_HOSTS.clear()
add_virtualhost(DEFAULT_URL_HOST,DEFAULT_EMAIL_HOST)
add_virtualhost("104.131.98.138","lists.example.org")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, pardon me for misdirection here because I misunderstanding your intention *in the past*. Now, as far as I understand, your intention is aliasing 104.131.98.138 to lists.freedomlayer.org - so when you browse through either `104.131.98.138` and `lists.freedomlayer.org` you get same result - YES?

Unfortunately, it isn't possible with mailman. Mailman expect single unique URL for every list. More info, click [this FAQ](http://wiki.list.org/x/lYA9) from mailman documentation

Anyway you can set redirection in Apache. So whenever user doesn't use `http://lists.freedomlayer.org` to go to mailman web page (i.e. using `http://104.131.98.138`) it will redirected to http://lists.freedomlayer.org.

Here the apache config to get your redirection works

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^lists\.freedomlayer\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://lists.freedomlayer.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried adding the line as suggested. I still have two different pages though. This time in the access through IP address case I get the mail address as mailman@lists.example.org (Earlier It was mailman@ip-address), so it did make some difference.

Comment: @real two suggestions: (1) could you replace `add_virtualhost(DEFAULT_URL_HOST,DEFAULT_EMAIL_HOST)` with `add_virtualhost('192.168.99.99', 'lists.example.com')`  in mm_cfg.py and restart mailman (2) If it still fails please post the screenshot also :)

Comment: Thanks again for your message. I tried replacing the lines, however I get similar results. If it helps somehow, the full configuration is here: https://github.com/realcr/mailman_docker

Comment: Thanks, for the docker. However when I tried to play it in my bare new VPS, it doesn't works because permission issue.

Comment: As docker expects to run as root, you should add sudo to all of my scripts. Did the permission issue showed up from the host, or inside the container?

Comment: Inside the container. I had to run `check_perms -f` before `service mailman restart` :). Anyway this is OOT (we can continue in github though :)). See my updated answer

Comment: I understand the idea you propose here. I think this what I'm going to do eventually. Just one more comment about it: I think using mod alias in this case could be a bit cleaner. (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html). Thank you for your help. Be sure to send me a message if the docker thing still doesn't work for you.

Comment: You can try to use mod_alias in this case (I don't know that will works or not). Please edit my answer in case you have alternative way to getting redirection works.